# Wiremock proxy stub issue

Tags: wiremock

Wiremock proxy stub runs on port 1234 with host http://example.com, but httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()  gives connection refused error.

```
wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlMatching(".*"))              
                .willReturn(aResponse().proxiedFrom("http://example.com:1234")));





ConnectionFactory conFac = new ConnectionFactory("http://example.com", 1234);
   HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = conFac.getHttpURLConnection(new URL(new URI("http", null, "http://example.com", 1234, null, null, null).toString()));
   httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WireMock to act as a proxy of `http://example.com`, then you missunderstand what `proxiedFrom` stand for. It's used for forwarding your request received by your local wiremock server to the other website. For example, you set up wiremock running on `localhost:8888`. Then, you set up something like  `proxiedFrom("example.com")`. As a result, what ever sending to `localhost:8888/rooms/{id}` will be forwarding to `example.com/rooms/{id}`.

[WireMock proxy Documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/)

Answer (score 0):

WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().proxyVia("http://example.com", 79));

Tried proxyVia()...   httpURLConnection.getResponseCode(); gives java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

```
ConnectionFactory conFac = new ConnectionFactory("http://example.com", 1234);
   HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = conFac.getHttpURLConnection(new URL(new URI("http", null, "http://example.com", 1234, null, null, null).toString()));
   httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is 1234 and not 79. Still throws ConectException

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().proxyVia("http://example.com", 1234));
```

Comment: Does WireMock supports proxyVia() or proxyFrom() or responseTransformer ?